# Importing Product image in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, import, product-images

I am getting following error when I am trying to import CSV file as Product import.

[image]

I used following commands for access permission.

```
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
```

I increased **php execution** time in apache server.

I used **item_xxl_12063874_18123233.jpg**  as base-image in CSV file.

I used **pub/media/import** as Images File Directory in Product import screen and placed all the images in **pub/media/import**.

Here is CSV file formate

[image]

Comment: please show your csv file format with image value.

Comment: Thanks @RakeshJesadiya. I added CSV file format with image value.

Comment: Compare your image extension. If it's **image.JPG** in media folder and **image.jpg** in your csv, then the image will not be imported. Image name is case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks @DineshYadav. I checked all the extension and images. All are same like `image.jpg`.

Comment: It worked when i skipped the images file directory path textbox ( already copied the required files to pub media import)

Answer (score 2):

**Import Images from the Local Server**

**1.** On the Magento server, upload the image files to the pub/media/import folder. This is the default folder for importing product images.

> [magento installation folder]/pub/media/import

You can use a different folder on the Magento server, as long as the path to the folder is specified during the import process.

**2.** In the CSV data, enter the name of each image file to be imported on the correct row, by sku, and in the correct column according to image type (`base_image`, `small_image`, `thumbnail_image`, or `additional_images`).

For images in the default import folder(`/pub/media/import`), do not include the path before the filename in the CSV data.

The CSV file must include only the sku column and the related image columns.

[image]

CSV Import Image from Default Location

**3.** Follow the instructions to import the data.

After selecting the file to import, enter the relative path following Images File Directory:

> /pub/media/import

[image]

**Images File Directory**

If importing multiple images for a single sku, insert a blank row below the sku, and enter the additional image file names in the appropriate columns. The additional rows are understood to belong to the parent sku.

Comment: Thanks @Nikunj Vadariya. I followed all your instructions before but I was facing that error. I added CSV file format with image value. I think this can help you to know about the error.

Answer (score 2):

This error comes when image not available on given path.

Use / before image name in your csv file. 
eg. /my_image.jpg.

If you add all image in var/import directory then add **Images File Directory** path as follow

```
var/import
```

Make sure all images are available in var/import folder. It should not contain in other folder in import folder. `e.g var/import/myfolder/my_image.jpg`

**`It should be var/import/my_image.jpg`**

Make sure permission related to var and pub folder. It should be readable and writable.